# Newman + Postmant Specify a single environment variable via command line

Tags: javascript, json, http, testing, postman

I'm using newman and postman to run a suite of postman request and associated test scripts.

I have an environment variable that is a sensitive piece of information that I cannot store on disk (therefore I can't declare it inside of the JSON test file). I need to have some simple way for it to be passed into the tests.

I would like to assign a value to the environment variable on the command line as an argument when I run the tests.

I run the tests like so:

`newman run c:\path\to\test.json`

I want to do something like this:

`newman run c:\path\to\test.json passwordEnvVariable=mypassword`

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 4):

For environment variable use:

```
newman run c:\path\to\test.json --env-var passwordEnvVariable=mypassword
```

According to newman documentation:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman

Answer (score 1):

According to newman's [document](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman#command-line-options), there is no such option. Right now, the only way to pass environment variable is passing a file path or URL.

However, @michaelajr raised a feature request 8 days ago (May 4th), which is exactly what you want: [Pass environment variables on the command line](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/1013). As newman team has acknowledged this feature and no workaround is posted in the thread, it is unlikely to find a workaround either.

Wish newman will add this feature soon.

Answer (score 1):

Try this key:

```
--global-var <value>            Allows the specification of global variables via the command line, in a key=value format
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running my `collection` through postman's APIs with an `environment` in the also from the APIs and then overriding just one variable locally. I [used this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50418567/2249725) to find my uids. and then ran something like this after adding `POSTMAN_API_KEY` into my `.zshrc` file

```bash
newman run "https://api.getpostman.com/collections/$uid?apikey=$POSTMAN_API_KEY" \
    --env-var "password=mypassword" \
    # environment file needs to be after local values
    --environment "https://api.getpostman.com/environments/$uid?apikey=$POSTMAN_API_KEY"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `newman run collection.json --global-var "<global-variable-name>=<global-variable-value>"`

Comment: Please explain your answer. It will be helpful for future users.