# How to get Postman Environment and Postman Globals URLs for passing to Newman?

Tags: postman, newman

Newman help specifies that collection, environment and globals can be passed as a path or as a URL. I can see how to get a collection URL from Postman (by going to Share > Collection Link).
How can I get the URLs to Environment and Globals in Postman, so I could pass them to newman?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: how come you didn't find something to try from newman help ?

Answer (score 11):

Using Newman with the Postman Pro API:

1. Generate an API key
2. Fetch a list of your collections from:

   ```
   https://api.getpostman.com/collections?apikey=$apiKey
   ```
3. Get the collection link via its UID:

   ```
   https://api.getpostman.com/collections/$uid?apikey=$apiKey
   ```
4. Obtain the environment URI from:

   ```
   https://api.getpostman.com/environments?apikey=$apiKey
   ```
5. Using the collection and environment URIs acquired in steps 3 and 4, run the collection as follows:

   ```
   newman run "https://api.getpostman.com/collections/$uid?apikey=$apiKey" \
       --environment "https://api.getpostman.com/environments/$uid?apikey=$apiKey"
   ```

[Link to Newman package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman)

Answer (score 2):

Using the Postman desktop app please try the following steps -

1. View your collection in Postman
2. From the collection details view
   (press the arrow next to the collection name) and select `View in Web`.
3. In the Postman web view, next to the Postman logo on the right, there is a drop-down.
4. From the drop-down select the **Workspace** where your test collection is in.
5. On the Collection list page, you will see **Environments** as a tab next to Collections.
6. Select the Environments tab, then select the specific environment you want.
7. The URL on this page is the Environment's URL you can use for Postman.

Answer (score 0):

via Postman, I exported my environment as a json file, and then hosted that file on a webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get that how to get Postman Globals URLs for passing to Newman?
I am only able to get the collection and Environment URL.

Answer (score -4):

From the command line, use the newman [command line options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#command-line-options):

```
-e <source>, --environment <source>
Specify an environment file path or URL. Environments provide a set 
of variables that one can use within collections. Read More

-g <source>, --globals <source>
Specify file path or URL for global variables. Global variables are 
similar to environment variables but has a lower precedence and can 
be overridden by environment variables having same name.
```

If you use newman as a [Node JS module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#api-reference), provide environment and global as options to newman.run():

```
newman.run({environment: <source>, globals: <source>}, callback)
```

Comment: This is all good once you've got the URL for the environment or globals. The actual question was where to get these URLs from!
I'll explain: In Postman Pro you can share a collection and in Collection Link there is a URL that can be passed to newman. There is no Environment Link or Globals Link(or even share) option. So how can I obtain the URL of Environment and Globals in Postman Pro?